# Как собрать данный макрос?

Tags: c

Мне нужно собрать такой макрос, который будет принимать массив бежать по каждому его элементу и переставлять биты внутри этого элемента таким образом, что самый правый байт становиться на место самого левого, а левый на место правого, потом дальше следующий байт справа на место следующего слева, а левый с правым.

Я написал вот такой макрос

```
#define reverse(arr, size)({\
        int i; \
        int tmp;\
        int inside;\
        int tmp_size;\
        char left;\
        char right\
        for(i = 0; i < (size); i++)\
            tmp = (arr)[i]\
            tmp_size = sizeof(tmp)\
            for(inside = 0; inside < tmp_size; inside++)\
                left = tmp[inside];\
                right = tmp[tmp_size - inside]\
                tmp[inside] = right\
                tmp[tmp_size - inside] = left})\
```

Во первых я не уверен, что он написан правильно, так как не могу проверить из за ошибки которую получаю когда пробую его вызвать

```
int main() {

    int arr_size = 8;
    int arr[arr_size];
    int arr_result[arr_size];
    int idx;

    for (idx = 0; idx < arr_size; ++idx) {
        arr[idx] = idx;
    }

    reverse(arr, arr_size);

    return 0;
}
```

```
====================[ Build | test_c | Debug ]==================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/aleksey/CLionProjects/test_c/cmake-build-debug --target test_c -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target test_c
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_c.dir/main.c.o
/Users/aleksey/CLionProjects/test_c/main.c:39:5: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    reverse(arr, arr_size);
    ^
/Users/aleksey/CLionProjects/test_c/main.c:18:9: note: expanded from macro 'reverse'
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)\
        ^
/Users/aleksey/CLionProjects/test_c/main.c:39:5: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
    reverse(arr, arr_size);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/aleksey/CLionProjects/test_c/main.c:23:28: note: expanded from macro 'reverse'
                right = tmp[tmp_size - inside]\
                        ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

Что делаю не так?

**P.S.** По заданию нужно выполнить это как макрос

Comment: У вас же в половине месть ; отсутствуют. Прям в логе ошибки написано:) и внимательно посмотрите на вторую ошибку. Array у вас чем является и как с ним работать)

Comment: Зачем тут макрос? Сделайте обычную функцию. В крайнем случае оберните вызов функции в макрос.

Comment: @user7860670 По заданию нужно выполнить как макрос, добавил в вопрос

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду. И насчет Array не совсем понял, а чем он является? И как с ним работать?

Comment: Напишите 2 макроса. Один пробегает по массиву и для каждого элемента вызывает второй, передавая адрес элемента массива и его размер  в байтах. Второй макрос переставляет байты в своем аргументе.

Comment: Конкретно сейчас у вас компилятор ругается на отсутствие `;` после многих операторов. Вообще же, я бы писал макросы вот в таком формате `#define REVERSE(a, sz) ({ внутри фигурных скобок код, обращения к аргументам a и sz лучше заключать в (), каждая строка завершается \  значение последнего выражения во внешних {} будет значением, которое возвращает макрос })`

Comment: @avp исправил в вопросе. и я так понял, что обращение к битам у меня не верное, нужно масками пользоваться вроде как. чтоб определить какой бит 1 или 0 и потом менять их местами

Comment: Так вам байты внутри int (их 4 штуки) надо переставить (так в тексте вопроса написано) или биты? (а их уже 32)

Comment: @avp да биты, исправил вопрос

Comment: Биты однозначно не так переставляются...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте. По идее должно работать для всех размеров целых чисел.

```
#define GET_BIT(v, bno) (((v) >> (bno)) & 1)
#define SET_BIT(v, bno, bv) ( ((v) & ~(1ULL << (bno)))                  \
                              | (((unsigned long long)(bv) & 1) << (bno)))
#define REV_BITS(x) ({__typeof__(x) u = x;                      \
      for (int left = sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1, right = 0;      \
           left > right; left--, right++) {                     \
        int lbv = GET_BIT(u, left), rbv = GET_BIT(u, right);    \
        u = SET_BIT(u, right, lbv); u = SET_BIT(u, left, rbv);  \
      } u;})
#define REVERSE_BITS(array, n) ({                       \
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                       \
        (array)[i] = REV_BITS((array)[i]); })
```

Константа `CHAR_BIT` определена в `<limits.h>`. Это количество бит в байте (точнее в типе `char`) (ага, бывают архитектуры, например TMS, где это число может быть не равно всем привычным восьми).

На всякий случай для перестановки байт тоже написал.

```
#define REVERSE_BYTES(array, n) ({                      \
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                       \
        REV_BYTES((array) + i); })
#define REV_BYTES(a) ({ unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)(a);        \
      int r = sizeof(*(a)) - 1;                                         \
      for (int l = 0; l < r; l++, r--) {                                \
        unsigned char c = p[l]; p[l] = p[r]; p[r] = c;                  \
      }})
```

Собственно, макрос `REV_BITS` можно сделать более оптимальным, определив макрос, скажем, `SET_2BITS(v, bno1, bv1, bno2, bv2)` аналогичный `SET_BIT`. Там надо сразу сбрасывать в ноль 2 бита `(v) & ~((1ULL << bno1) | (1ULL << bno2))` и устанавливать их в нужные значения.

Но это уж вы сами можете потренироваться.

Программка для тестирования что-то вроде

```
int
main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  unsigned short arr[4] = {0, -1, 1, 0xff55aa01};

  long z = SET_BIT(0, 7, 1);
  printf("z 7 %016lx\n", z);
  z = SET_BIT(0x70abcdef, 31, 1);
  printf("z 31 %016lx\n", z);

  REVERSE_BITS(arr, 4);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%016x\n", arr[i]);

  REVERSE_BYTES(arr + 3, 1);
  printf("%016x\n", arr[3]);  

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Меняете на разные типы и т.п., запускаете и смотрите.